# My low beams only work sometimes

Tags: ford, intermittent-problems

Why do my low beams work then I use my brights or shut my truck off for a half hour or so and turn it back on my low beams don't work but my high beams do?

Comment: Do you have "plug and play" HID bulbs?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Which Ford truck is this? And which model year is it?

Comment: If it’s HID could the ballast be overheating?

Comment: 2001 f150  I put aftermarket lights in it cause I thought it could be somethi g with the bulk

Comment: Bulbs but it still does it